# Nodejs write json to a file

Tags: json, node.js

I just started learning nodejs. I am currently working with sockets and made chat program.

I want to save entire chat to a json file. Currently my code is this :

```
  socket.on('chat', function  (data) {
    message = {user : data.message.user, message : data.message.message};
    chat_room.sockets.emit('chat', {message: message});

    jsonString = JSON.stringify(message);

    fs.appendFile("public/chat.json", jsonString, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
    }); 

  });
```

This is currently working perfect, but the json which is written in file is wrong.

This gave me a wrong json

`{"user":"niraj","message":"hw r u?"}{"user":"ntechi","message":"hello"}{"user":"ntechi","message":"hw r u?"}`

The above code is called when message is triggered. I want json in this format

`{"user":"awd","message":"hw r u?","user":"ntechi","message":"hello","user":"ntechi","message":"hw r u?"}`

Can anyone help me in this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first set of wrong JSON is created because you are appending a piece of JSON to a file each time you get a message.

The second set of JSON is also wrong - each property name has to be unique.

Presumably you want something like:

```
[
{"user":"niraj","message":"hw r u?"},
{"user":"ntechi","message":"hello"},
{"user":"ntechi","message":"hw r u?"}
]
```

In which case the logic you need to use is:

1. Read data from file
2. Parse data as JSON and assign to a variable
3. In the event of an error, assign an empty array to that variable
4. `push` the message object onto the end of the array
5. stringify the array
6. Overwrite the file with the new string

Comment: thanks it worked
I am now reading the json file, storing it as a string in a variable and by using `concat` I am attaching two variables and writing entire json to that file.